# Data overlapping while plotting the graph

Tags: python, flask, web, plot, charts

In SQLite there's "episode" table which has seasonNumber and episodeNumber. The problem is that when plotted they don't go in the order of the seasons, because the first episode of any season starts with a value of 1, not the previous season's maximum value + 1. I know that for the correct display on the chart, I need to change the values ​​​​of all episodes except the first season, but I don’t know how. Or is there another way to do it?

Might be useful (SQL tables):

1. Columns in "episode":
   tconst   parentTconst    seasonNumber    episodeNumber
2. In "ratings":
   tconst   averageRating   numVotes
3. and "basics":
   tconst   titleType   primaryTitle    originalTitle   isAdult startYear   endYear runtimeMinutes  genres

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    # Connect to CS50 SQL database
    db = cs50.SQL("sqlite:///imdb.db")

    # Query data from database
    data = db.execute("""
        SELECT e.episodeNumber, r.averageRating, e.seasonNumber
        FROM episode AS e
        JOIN ratings AS r ON e.tconst = r.tconst
        JOIN basics AS b ON e.parentTconst = b.tconst
        WHERE b.titleType = 'tvSeries'
        ORDER BY e.seasonNumber, e.episodeNumber;
    """)

    # Process data for plotting
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['episodeNumber', 'averageRating', 'seasonNumber'])

    # Calculate the index of the first episode of season 2
    season2_start = df[df['seasonNumber'] == 2].index[0]

    # Add the number of episodes in the first season to the episode numbers of season 2
    df.loc[season2_start:, 'episodeNumber'] += df.loc[season2_start-1, 'episodeNumber'] - df.loc[season2_start-1, 'seasonNumber'] * df[df['seasonNumber'] == 1]['episodeNumber'].iloc[-1]

    # Create Plotly chart
    fig = px.scatter(df, x='episodeNumber', y='averageRating', title='Episode Ratings')

    # Set y-axis range and step
    fig.update_layout(
        yaxis=dict(
            range=[0, 10],  # set the range of the y-axis to be 0-10
            tick0=0,  # set the starting tick to be 0
            dtick=1  # set the tick step to be 1
        )
    )

    # Return Plotly chart to template
    plot_div = fig.to_html(full_html=False)
    return render_template('index.html', plot_div=plot_div)
```

I tried to sort using ORDER BY in SQL but it was useless.